# Python & Selenium Scrapers on VPS - Lag Issues

Tags: python, django, selenium, web-scraping, vps

Here's the basic set-up:
Python 2 on Django
Selenium & BeautifulSoup
MqSQL

I built a search engine. Upon a user entering search criteria, I fill in forms based on the query, scrape the data from said sources, using my algorithm to sort and organize the data, and displays the results to the user.

Multiply this by a number of scrapers + number of users and this has become a nightmare.

My hosting provider stated that certain processes are overloading the RAM on the vps causing the site to stall like a DDoS. The processes so far are:
1. Xvfb
2. Apache2
3. Chrome
4. A python script to initialize the scrapers

Question 1: How can I best optimize the above processes to have as little imprint as possible (aka. to know if I really need to up the RAM on the vps)?

Question 2: What's the best starting server set-up for a project like this? I'm currently running on 2 nodes w/ 2gb RAM + high bandwidth boosts that scales to 4gb RAM. Thoughts on this?

Comment: There is no silver bullet for this. It's exactly why search engine scaling is so expensive. It's the nature of the app.

Comment: try http://phantomjs.org/, they have a selenium driver

Comment: @AviahLaor That's exactly the answer I was afraid of. We're a start-up and we gained popularity very quickly. 

I'm all ears for suggestions if you have any though.

Comment: @AviahLaor Will try PhantomJS and let you know. This will eliminate the need for Xvfb script and the chrome browser correct?

Comment: @AviahLaor So I changed up some of the scrapers and did some initial tests. So far, it is using less memory with similar scraper performance as before. However, I read that PhantomJS may still have memory leak issues that could crash it. Has this been resolved in v2.1?